# Perforce: creating a bundle in a held state

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to create a bundle of files with perforce so that it is in a "held" state, not checked in, so that it can be retrieved easily?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like the "shelve" functionality might be what you're looking for. The documentation is [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/shelve.html). Basically it keeps the files on the server, but they're not actually submitted. You (or others) can then "unshelve" the changes into your clientspec.

If your server version (2009.2 or earlier) doesn't support shelving, you might also want to check out [p4tar](http://public.perforce.com/wiki/P4tar), which can package a changelist into a file that can later be restored to your workspace.